# Sync. emails using imap java

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap, synchronization

I have written a code which **Downloads all the mails and store them**, but now I want to **synchronize the mails**..that is, **download only those mails which have not been downloaded earlier**.

**Note**: sync does not mean downloading only unseen messages...
Any help or Idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Study the IMAP protocol, IMAP has seen / unseen flags. You could also delete the message once you download them or move to a different folder

Comment: Use the UIDs, download UIDS you haven't seen before, remove UIDS no longer on the server, fetch flags for everything else.

Answer (score 4):

For this you can use message UID's to check for the messages...the maximum Uid is of the message which is most recent...Synchronization basically include two parts:

1. **Fetching new messages** which does not exist in database.For that store the UID of message you last downloaded(and has maximum value) and download all mails from the previous maximum UID value to new UID value.
   2.**Removing deleted messages** from the database .For this check the values of UID's that are missing and delete them .
   Although values of UID are folder specific and may change for a particular message but it happens rarely now and you  can check this by UIDvalidity .
   If you are using java there are functions called **getUID()** and **getUIDValidity()**
   link: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html
   RFC4549 states about how the synchronization needs to be done.
   link :https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4549

Answer (score 1):

> but now I want to synchronize the mails

Synchronise means any new mails in mailbox as well as modifications to the existing mails. Modifications can be changing flags or even deleting.

If your IMAP Store supports IDLE command, you can issue IDLE command on certain folder and listen to any changes to that mailbox.

Since you cannot issue IDLE command on all folders, you can maintain HIGHESTMODSEQ and LAST_UID value (if your IMAP Store supports CONDSTORE) for a folder and look for changes in a folder since LAST_UID and HIGHESTMODSEQ using **uidfetchChangedSince** method

From its documentations,

```
   /**
     * Get the sequence numbers for messages changed since the given
     * modseq and with UIDs ranging from start till end.
     * Also, prefetch the flags for the returned messages.
     *
     * @param   start   first UID
     * @param   end last UID
     * @param   modseq  the MODSEQ
     * @return      array of sequence numbers
     * @exception   ProtocolException   for protocol failures
     * @see "RFC 4551"
     * @since   JavaMail 1.5.1
     */
    public int[] uidfetchChangedSince(long start, long end, long modseq)
            throws ProtocolException
```

Using message numbers, you can always get complete message.